# Azure Cognitive Services: Custom text classification answering 404 on retrieve request

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-ai

So I made Custom Multi label model on Azure and I deployed. Right now I've been trying to follow the instructions of to do the requests. The cURL to submit works well with 202 but the one to retrieve it returns: `{"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}`. This is the requests without some private info:
Submit:

```
curl -X POST "<endpoint>/language/analyze-text/jobs?api-version=<version>" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: key" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"tasks\":[{\"kind\":\"CustomMultiLabelClassification\",\"parameters\":{\"projectName\":\"prjName\",\"deploymentName\":\"model\"}}],\"displayName\":\"CustomTextPortal_CustomMultiLabelClassification\",\"analysisInput\":{\"documents\":[{\"id\":\"document_CustomMultiLabelClassification\",\"text\":\"Hello world!\",\"language\":\"en\"}]}}"
```

Retrieve:

```
curl <endpoint>/language/analyze-text/jobs?api-version=<version> -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: key"
```

Is it just bugged or is just not working anymore or Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is missing the -X GET method and the job ID in the URL. The correct format should be:

```
curl -X GET "<endpoint>/language/analyze-text/jobs/{jobId}?api-version=<version>" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: key"
```